# unable to retrieve data from cache in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, caching, drop-down-menu, bind

i am new to ASP.NET,

i am making Country, state dropdownlist.

for eg: For particular country, i will read states of that country from Cache file.

***LOGIC :*** when user visits first time, at that time cache will be empty so corresponding states will be fetched from `XMLFile` and inserts it's states into cache, next time when user visits same country so it's states should fetched from cache and not from `XMLFile`.

**i am unable to fetch states of required country in my Dropdownlist...**

here is my code snippet,

```
protected void DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           string  SelectedCountry = DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.Text;

           XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));

           var query = from country in doc.Descendants("country")
                       where country.Attribute("name").Value == SelectedCountry
                       select new
                       {
                           states = from state in country.Elements("state")
                                    select new{
                                        Name = state.Attribute("name").Value
                                    }
                       };

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));

            if (Cache["key"]==null)
            {
                foreach (var st in query)
                {
                    foreach (var StateName in st.states)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Name"] = StateName.Name;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        Cache.Insert("key", dr);

                    }
                }
                DropDownListState.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownListState.DataTextField = "Name";
                DropDownListState.DataBind();


            }
            else
            {
                      object obj = Cache["key"];
                      dt.Rows.Add(obj);

                DropDownListState.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownListState.DataTextField = "Name";
                DropDownListState.DataBind();
            }        
    }
```

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with this code, like the way data and UI are handled, Cache is used, plus a bug, cache keys should be unique per object.

So let's refactor a bit the code and create a method which returns a DataTable with the states  by country name. If the states are already in cache, that DataTable in cache will be returned.

```
private static DataTable GetStates(string countryName)
{
   DataTable dt = HttpContext.Current.Cache[countryName] as DataTable;
   if (dt != null)
       return dt;

   // the datatable is not in cache, let's create it then and add it to cache, next call will pick it from cache and won't read and parse the xml again
   var doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));
   var query = from country in doc.Descendants("country")
                 where country.Attribute("name").Value == countryName
                 select new
                 {
                     states = from state in country.Elements("state")
                              select new
                              {
                                  Name = state.Attribute("name").Value
                              }
                 };

  dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));

 foreach (var st in query)
            {
                foreach (var StateName in st.states)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Name"] = StateName.Name;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                }
            }
 // add the data table in the cache (not a row and don't use the same key)
 HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(countryName, dt);   
 // return this table
 return dt;
}
```

Now the event handler

```
protected void DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var countryName = DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
       var dt = GetStates(countryName);

       DropDownListState.DataSource = dt;
       DropDownListState.DataTextField = "Name"; // you can set it in markup also
       DropDownListState.DataBind();
    }
```

Cache is shared by all users, so if this is your intention then is ok to use it.

Comment: it shows me error like `object ref required for non static field system.web.caching.cache.insert(string,object)`

Comment: try with HttpContext.Current.Cache, I've just edited my answer

Comment: `object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property` error in var doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));

Comment: I made another edit ( I didn't compile this code, if the metod wouldn't be static, it woudln't have been these issues). The Cache and Server objects can be accessed either via HttpContext static class or via the Page properties. Clearly if the method is static, the Page properties can't be accessed. Sorry for not paying more attention to this, we would have saved some time.

Comment: dude code is compiled successfully, but m unable to reteirve country in my dropdown list

Comment: you can pastebin markup and code behind, I'll have a look. But debug first to see where is the problem

Comment: `XMLFile.xml` http://pastebin.com/Ttqt50Eh  AND  `.aspx`  http://pastebin.com/bTqPV6Gw

Comment: not working.. `protected void DropDownListCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` is not getting fired

Comment: But you don't add the countries in the countries dropdown

Comment: You'll have to populate that dropdown too

Comment: great work dude.. it's working... if i can vote up your ans 100 times.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
private DataTable PopulateCountryList()
{
  DataTable dt = (DataTable)Cache["countries"];

  if (dt == null)
  {
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile.xml"));

    var query = from country in doc.Descendants("country")
    where country.Attribute("name").Value == SelectedCountry
    select new
    {
        states = from state in country.Elements("state")
        select new {
        Name = state.Attribute("name").Value
        }
    };

    foreach (var st in query)
    {
        foreach (var StateName in st.states)
        {
          DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
          dr["Name"] = StateName.Name;
          dt.Rows.Add(dr);    
        }
    }

    Cache.Insert("countries", dt, null, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
  }

  return = dt;
}
```

When you want to populate he Dropdown:

```
DropDownListState.DataSource = PopulateCountryList();
DropDownListState.DataTextField = "Name"; 
DropDownListState.DataBind();
```